# QML ListView display only 1 row ( if covered in Column and row )

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I need to put a ListView ( coded in QML) into a Row, but in this case only first Row of the ListView is displayed . Some idea why ? Here is my example :

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
 import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

 Page {
     id: test


      Column {
          spacing: units.gu(1)
          id: pageLayout
          anchors {
              margins: units.gu(2)
              fill: parent
          }


          Row {
              id: listarea
              spacing: units.gu(1)

              ListModel {
                  id: fruitModel
                  ListElement {
                      name: "Apple"
                      cost: 2.45
                  }
                  ListElement {
                      name: "Orange"
                      cost: 3.25
                  }
                  ListElement {
                      name: "Banana"
                      cost: 1.95
                  }
              }

             ListView {
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 model: fruitModel
                 delegate: Row {
                     Text { text: "Fruit: " + name }
                     Text { text: "Cost: $" + cost }
                 }
             }
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **anchors.fill: parent** on your Row

Comment: If I have in first row buttons and in second row the ListView, they are overwriten. Any suggestions what's wrong ?

Comment: If you are going to have more than the ListView, you'll need to give it an explicit height, otherwise the Column won't know where to put the others